# Creating EF 4 Migrations that includes Collections

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to create a migrations for my blog using EF4 but I'm not sure how declare the fields with are generic collections such as `Posts`. How can this be done? When using intellesense, no generic types are available to declare a property.

```
 CreateTable("Blogs", t => new
     {
         Id = t.Int(false, true),
         Title = t.String(),
         BloggerName = t.String(),
         Posts = t.ICollection<Post>()  //no ICollection
     }).PrimaryKey(k => k.Id);
```

Comment: MVC has nothing do do with entity framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are mixing migrations a bit with the entity in code first and in this case would want to create another table called "Posts" that would have a foreign key relationship with the "Blogs" table.

```
 CreateTable("Posts", c => new
 {
     Id = c.Int(false, true),
     Content = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 512)
 }).PrimaryKey(k => k.Id)
 .ForeignKey("Blogs", t => t.Id);
```

It is generally easier to build the entities as classes (code first) and then let the migration tooling generate the migrations themselves in the console, e.g.

```
Add-Migration "BlogPosts"
```